# const char pointer template specialization

Tags: c++, template-specialization, string-literals

I have this piece of code:

```
template<typename T>
void test(const T& p);
```

And I wanted to specialize template with const char* to handle string literals. So I added:

```
template<>
void test(const char* const& p) { std::cout << "test2\n"; }
```

But it turns out it doesn't work with call:

```
test("abc");
```

I know that "abc" is not technically const char pointer so I should write this:

```
template<size_t N>
void test(const char (&p)[N]) { std::cout << "test3\n"; }
```

But I don't want to differientiate between string literal and const char*, eg.:

```
const char* s = "abc";
test(s); test("abc"); // I want it to call the same function
```

So I found out that if you write "template specialization" (which is actually just overload) like this:

```
void test(const char* const& p) { std::cout << "test4\n"; }
```

it works and test("abc") and test(s) calls the same function. Why is that happening? And can I write actual template specialization for const char* and string literals because above feels like a hack - not the big one but still.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I thought it was a joke because you changed std::cout << "test3\n"; to std::cout << "test2\n" so that the function's body was the same haha.

Comment: @HubertObrzut  Just sloppy reading (and typing) on my part. Sorry :)

Answer (score 4):

You can add another template, like so:

```
template<typename T>
void test(const T* p);
```

And then you can do:

```
template<>
void test(const char* p) { std::cout << "test2\n"; }
```

However, I don't see anything wrong with just adding a plain-old non-templated function overload to handle the `const char *` case:

```
void test(const char* p) { std::cout << "test4\n"; }
```

In fact, I much prefer it (because otherwise you get a separate instantiation for each different string you pass to `test`).

Comment: Ok that pointer template specialization makes sense - it feels obvious now but I concentrated too much on those references, but still, just out of curiosity, why template specialization and overload with the same signatures are not picked in the same situations, because test2 and test4 are "the same" functions - one is just template specialization with template<>?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.  Do you mean what happens if you have both?  Ambiguous definitions, at a guess.

Comment: No I mean that if you have `template<> void test(const char* const& p) {...}`, `test("abc")` won't work, but if you have just `void test(const char* const& p) {...}`, `test("abc")` will work.

Comment: You actually get a linker error with the templated version, "undefined reference to `void test<char [4]>(char const (&) [4])'", which gives you a bit of a clue.

Comment: Yeah I know that it doesn't work and the error, but why string literal "abc" can be converted to const char* const& without template but with it can't be. In clarification why these functions give different results, but they have the same signatures and everything, one is just template specialization and the other one is just overload.

Comment: @HubertObrzut `void test(const char* const& p)` takes **a reference** to a `const char*` variable, but `"abc"` is not a `const char*` variable, it is a `const char[]` array, so `p` can't take a reference to it. `void test(const char* p)` will happily take `"abc"` though, thanks to *array decay*.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't think you understand the question. If you have function `template<typename T> void test(const T&);` and you write template specialization `template<> void test(const char* const& p) {}`, function call `test("abc");` will give linker error, but if you write practically the same function - overload - `void test(const char* const& p) {}`, function call `test("abc");` will work. Why is that?

Comment: @HubertObrzut "*function call `test("abc");` will give linker error*" - [works for me](https://ideone.com/j3IFmt), but the specialization is not called for a string literal, only a variable. But the non-specialization overload is called for both. Sounds like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: @RemyLebeau well of course it works for you because you defined `template<typename T> void test(const T&)` function (I only declared it - I refer to my comment examples), but yeah, my point was that it doesn't call `template<> void test(const char* const&)`, but it calls `void test(const char* const&)`.